# Extended monitor - scroll right to access left screen

Tags: debian, xrandr, multi-monitor, monitors, crunchbang

I am running Crunchbang (debian based) and I'm trying to extend my desktop, I've ran the following command:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --auto --output DVI-I-1 --primary --auto
```

This has extended the desktop but my second monitor is to the left of my main monitor but I have to move the mouse to the right to access the left monitor, how can I fix this?

Output of `xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-I-2 connected 1680x1050+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set which screen is to the left of which with `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --primary --output DVI-I-2 --auto --left-of DVI-I-1
```

From `man xrandr`:

```
   --left-of, --right-of, --above, --below, --same-as another-output
          Use one of these options to position the output relative to  the
          position  of  another  output.  This allows convenient tiling of
          outputs within the screen.  The position is always computed rel‐
          ative  to  the  new  position  of the other output, so it is not
          valid to say --output a --left-of b --output b --left-of a.
```

Comment: While that fixes the mouse problem it also puts my main desktop to my left and my main monitor is now the extended one.

Comment: @Colin747 just change the options around. Which one do you want as primary? `DVI-I-1` or `DVI-I-2`? Which one should be to the right of which?

Comment: I think it's DVI-I-2 that should be my main one. (Is there anyway to identify which is which?)

Comment: @Colin747 unplug one and run `xrandr`. Anyway, the general format is `xrandr --output X --right-of Y`.

Comment: OK I want DVI-I-1 to be my main and DVI-I-2 to be extended to my left.

Comment: @Colin747 see updated answer. The options are pretty much self explanatory, hey do what it says on the cover: `--primary` defines your main screen and `--left-of X` positions it.

Comment: I just ran your updated answer and it is still switching my main display to the screen on my left.

Comment: @Colin747 strange. Is this one better? `xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --auto --output DVI-I-1 --auto --right-of DVI-I-2 --primary`

Comment: That made no difference, no matter I've got used to it by this point, thanks for the help though